# Oracle - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I just can't find what is wrong here. Trying to select path to the article pictures.
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
select artnr, listagg(path, bildnr '.' filtyp) within group (order by bildnr) as sökväg
from kund 
where knr in (select knr
            from kundorder
            where ordnr in (select ordnr
            from orderrad
            where artnr in (select artnr
            from artikel
            where bildnr in (select bildnr
            from artikelbild))))
            order by artnr;
```

[image: An answer should be:]

Comment: Did you try to just select from `kund` to simplify the query and locate the problematic part? What is `bildnr '.' filtyp`? Also non-ascii characters cannot be used as column names without quotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious error is in `listagg` (missing concatenation):

```
No : listagg (path, bildnr '.' filtyp)
Yes: listagg (PATH, bildnr || '.' || filtyp)
```

The rest should be OK (as far as syntax is concerned; can't tell whether query will (or will not) return what you want).

---

Also, perhaps you'd rather switch to `JOIN`s instead of using bunch of nested subqueries, e.g.

```
  SELECT u.artnr,
         LISTAGG (u.PATH, u.bildnr || '.' || u.filtyp)
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY u.bildnr) AS sokvag
    FROM kund u
         JOIN kundorder o ON u.knr = o.knr
         JOIN orderrad r ON r.ordnr = o.ordnr
         JOIN artikel a ON a.artnr = r.artnr
         JOIN artikelbild b ON b.bildnr = a.bildnr
ORDER BY u.artnr;
```

---

As of **ORA-30496**: Argument should be a constant: apparently, that's true.

Code you'd like to run:

```
SQL> select listagg(e.ename, e.job ||'.'|| to_char(e.deptno))
  2           within group (order by null) result
  3  from emp e
  4  where rownum <= 3;
select listagg(e.ename, e.job ||'.'|| to_char(e.deptno))
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30496: Argument should be a constant.
```

Let's try to *fool* Oracle and "prepare" the separator:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select e.ename, e.job ||'.'||to_char(e.deptno) separator
  3     from emp e
  4     where rownum <= 3
  5    )
  6  select listagg(t.ename, t.separator)
  7           within group (order by null)
  8  from temp t;
select listagg(t.ename, t.separator)
                        *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-30496: Argument should be a constant.
```

Still no luck. But if a separator really is a constant (comma in my example), then it *works*:

```
SQL> select listagg(e.ename ||': ' || e.job, ', ')
  2           within group (order by null) result
  3  from emp e
  4  where rownum <= 3;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALLEN: SALESMAN, SMITH: CLERK, WARD: SALESMAN

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be some more issues with this. 
ORA-30496: Argument should be a constant

Comment: *Also, perhaps you'd rather switch to JOINs* - Only for `[0..N] to [0..1]` relationships, especially when aggregation takes place.

Comment: Baibs, it seems that you can't have that separator, it **must** be something "constant" (as Oracle says, e.g. comma, semi-colon, dash or something like that.

Comment: Another option (to keep all the paths within builnr and filtyp) is to `listagg` all `u.PATH`s by `u.bildnr, u.filtyp`, and then `listagg(agg_upath || u.bildnr || '.' || u.filtyp, ',')` (or whatever constant separator is desired).

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your work on this!